# Unable to send a pdf attachment in MS team

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, botframework, chatbot

I have create a simple test bot is MS team using Bot framework (C#). I want to add a functionality to send a pdf file in the conversation . When I am testing it in Web chat & bot emulator , its working fine , but when I want to send the pdf in the chat I am getting error

```
Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'Microsoft.Bot.Connector
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong . Is anyone know how to resolve this .

Here is my

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try {
   
        var url = "https://**blob.core.windows.net/**/XYZ.pdf"; 
        var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(new
            Attachment
        {
            Name = "Bot.pdf",
            ContentUrl = url,
            ContentType = "application/pdf"
        });
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.ContentUrl(url, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf,"Bot.pdf"));

        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(ex.Message+ex.Source), cancellationToken);
    }
    }
```

here is my bot manifest.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.16/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "version": "1.2.3",
  "manifestVersion": "1.16",
  "id": "ID",
  "packageName": "com.package.name",
  "name": {
    "short": "BOTBOT",
    "full": "BOTBOT"
  },
  "developer": {
    "name": "Technologies",
    "mpnId": "",
    "websiteUrl": "https://Technologies.com/",
    "privacyUrl": "https://Technologies.com/privacypolicy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://Technologies.com/terms-conditions"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "Technologies Stuff",
    "full": "Technologies Stuff"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "outline.png",
    "color": "color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "conversations",
      "scopes": [ "personal" ]
    },
    {
      "entityId": "about",
      "scopes": [ "personal" ]
    }
  ],
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "ID",
      "scopes": [ "personal", "groupChat", "team" ],
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "supportsCalling": false,
      "supportsVideo": false,
      "supportsFiles": true
    }
  ],
  "validDomains": [ "*.ngrok.io", "quickchart.io", "*.ngrok-free.app","*.azurewebsites.net","blob.core.windows.net","*.pdf"],
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "OTHER ID",
    "resource": "api://ct-kernalbot.azurewebsites.net/OTHER ID"
  }
}
```

I first tried to send a local file by convert in base64 file

```
data:application/pdf;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(fileData)}
```

Now I am using URL pdf file .
But still not getting the PDF in chat